# Как усыпить поток до определенного события

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть View:

```
public class View {
    public volatile String s;

    public void viewer() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField t = new JTextField();
        frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, t);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                s = t.getText();
            }
        });
    }
```

Есть контроллер:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        View view = new View();
        view.viewer();
        //Thread.sleep(20000);
        //while (view.s == null);
        System.out.println("smth");
    }
}
```

Как усыпить поток до тех пор, пока не произошло событие во View (пока не заполнили все поля)?
Я закомментил два моих варианта. Первый засыпает только на фиксированное время и, соответственно, не связан никак с событием. Второй с `while` работает отлично, но выглядит как-то неправильно.
Каков более грамотный способ, без загрузки системы ненужным циклом?

Comment: Не знаю стоит ли "усыплять" поток  возможно просто в `actionPerformed` добавить какой нибудь `callback`?,

Comment: Не пойму это как? По типу флага проверки добавить? Так как потом в исполнение контроллера приостановтить до флага? Или Вы не об этом?

Comment: вы пытаетесь реализовать MVC?

Comment: @faq700 Нет, я о функции которая будет вызываться на событии `actionPerformed` после `s = t.getText();` будет выполнятся ваша функция

Comment: Давно ничего не делал с Java, но мне кажется, что можно посмотреть на [conditions](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/locks-concurrent/condition/java-util-concurrent-locks-condition-example/)

Comment: А где, собственно, сама многопоточность?

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman Да MVC

Comment: @Victor Нет, после s = t.getText(); не должна стоять функция. Логика в том, что есть контроллер class Main и несколько вьюшек. Каждая запускается принимает от пользователя данные, передает в контроллер и закрывается. Контроллер получает - передает в модель, та запрашивает у контроллера другую вьюшку, с другой инфой от пользователя

Comment: @SomeFire ну Main - контроллер это первый поток. При создании Jframe генерируется автоматически второй поток. Так как GUI - это автоматически отдельный поток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае, можно воспользоваться `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`.

В одном потоке вы добавляете элемент в очередь. Из другого пытаетесь его получить, но если очередь пуста, то поток блокируется, ожидая появления элемента.

```
final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

//где то в коде 
//поток будет ждать
String value = queue.take();

//где то в другом потоке
queue.add("hello");
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот это действительно простой способ решения проблемы! Осталось еще разобраться в сути)))

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать методу `wait()` и `notify() / notifyAll()`.

Пример:

```
synchronized (objectForBlock) {
    <...>
    objectForBlock.wait(); // усыпит поток этот выполнения
    <...>
}
```

Когда нужно "разбудить" поток вызываете - `objectForBlock.notifyAll()` Это "разбудит"все потоки заблокированные по объекту `objectForBlock`

Comment: не стоит забывать, что возможны случайные пробуждения - `spurious wakeups`. Так что приведенный код не совсем корректен. Требуется вызов wait обернуть в цикл, а в нем проверять условие пробуждения

Comment: Как я понял wait() и notify() / notifyAll() не работают в статическом методе(. Только не понял почему

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял задачу, тут подойдет [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).
Еще обнаружил как-то давно неплохую статейку, которая сможет помочь. Она [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277669/). Там некоторые приемвы с потоками.

Comment: Имеет смысл привести в ответе пример работы `CountDownLatch` в данном случае.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Попробую разобраться в предложенной Вами конструкции. Жаль нет примера))